# How to fake $_FILES and fool move_uploaded_file()?

Tags: php, upload

I'm extending a custom platform which does 500+ lines of tests on an uploaded file.
I don't want to copy-paste those tests because of future updates.

Can I do anything else besides calling the page from within itself but with image upload via cURL?

Comment: I assume this test just consists of testing say, uploading and preparing a file right? If you "fool" $_FILES and move_uploaded_file then won't you be breaking the test and making it worth nothing? The whole point of a test is to test it irl.

Comment: Improve the code. Let it so 500+ lined of tests on any file, regardless of its origin.

Comment: These tests run for image upload, checking approved file formats, dimensions based on settings, watermark, thumbs gen, etc. Can't really optimize much.

Comment: I am a little confused now that I read this again: so what your trying to do is upload a file without uploading one? And pretend that a valid file has been uploaded? Hmm move_uploaded_file is a hard one to pass without actually giving it valid params

Comment: @Sammaye bingo. I just want to supply a local path, relative to the php script.

Comment: Well you could house a file locally to the PHP script and then copy it to tmp populate the fields of $_FILES and then carry on from there...that should work if your not looking to create the file dynamically as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resubmitting `$_POST` vars from within the same page to itself, via cURL.