# fool php's move_uploaded_file without using cURL?

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

hello everyone my question has already been asked here -- [How to fake $_FILES and fool move_uploaded_file()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269913/how-to-fake-files-and-fool-move-uploaded-file) -- but was never answered directly.

i am writing a wordpress plugin that needs to connect to a remote database, download a file, and then call another plugin's file import method. the other plugin is the store locator plus plugin. it has a bulk records upload function that takes a file upload from a form and gets geolocation data and then stores the form data in its database. ***i want to basically automate this process using wp-cron.***

here is the line that is problematic in that plugin:

```
if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['csvfile']['tmp_name'],$updir.'/'.$_FILES['csvfile']['name'])){
return;
}
```

now, its easy to write a file to /tmp and spoof the `$_FILES` superglobal, but `move_uploaded_file` stops me dead in my tracks. i looked into the source for this and i'm still not clear on how it checks to make sure a form was uploaded since the source is obscure...

i want to avoid getting into a mess with curl because of authentication and security etc. i also don't want to edit the SLP plugins files in case an update happens.

**TL;DR**

does anyone know a way to fool `move_uploaded_files` to be convinced that what is in `$_FILES` is "uploaded"?

thanks in advance!

Comment: [`override_function`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php)?

Comment: interesting @bishop! thanks. i will have to see if this works. i'll try and override the move_uploaded_functions in my plugin and then call the other plugin's method to see if it will work. i'm not sure how the scoping will work out though...